# Exoplayer Live streaming RTSP

Tags: android, streaming, exoplayer, rtmp

I have an Insta360 Pro camera that sends a streaming via RTSP through the local URL "rtsp://192.168.1.103/live/live". In my Android mobile application written in Java, I have an ExoPlayer that should play the streaming. However, the ExoPlayer waits for the stream to stop before playing the video, and I want it to be shown live in real-time. Below is the code for the ExoPlayer in the onCreate function of my activity.

```
    ExoPlayer player =
            new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                    .setMediaSourceFactory(
                            new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context).setLiveTargetOffsetMs(5000))
                    .build();

    // Per MediaItem settings.

    player.setPlaybackSpeed(1.02f);
    MediaItem mediaItem =
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri(videoUrl)
                    .setLiveConfiguration(
                            new MediaItem.LiveConfiguration.Builder().setMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.02f).build())
                    .build();
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    // Create a player instance.
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    // Prepare the player.
    player.prepare();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

I tried to use exoplayer to get the RTSP stream and I expect the streaming to be load in real time

Comment: Can you explain the problem in a little more detail - how long is the stream (time wise) and what do you mean by ExoPlayer waits for the stream to stop?